# Insert an online map source (from a website) into ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, import, online

Is there anyway to insert an online map source into ArcGIS? There are a lot of global maps which only is accessible by their websites, and there is no save option to save a part of these maps and use in GIS software. I would like to insert an online maps into ArcGIS to work on it.
To be more clear, I am not looking for a base map. It's a map that produced and developed by an institution. I just want to import the link of this website and open this map in ArcGIS.

Comment: You seem to be talking about a specific web site, can you give a link to it?  Are you talking about dynamic maps (provided by services) or static maps?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion ArcGIS base maps are good, If you mean from Map is something like satellite maps(Bing,Google,...). In ArcMap, open file menu and then select add data after that select add base map, these maps are free and remember before adding ArcGIS base map ArcGIS must be connect to their server. If add based map was active (not grey) ArcGIS is connected. 
you can use this link:
[How to add an online basemap in ArcGIS 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77014/how-to-add-an-online-basemap-in-arcgis-10)
another option is ArcBrutile
[link]https://arcbrutile.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by selecting Add Data From ArcGIS Online:
You will have to sign in using your ArcGIS Online credentials.

[image]

Comment: It's not a map from ArcGIS Online database.

Comment: yes, you're right - that way you can add feature and map services